# What is the mass/cross section of Dark Matter candidates?

Tags: dark-matter

I understand that experiments at LUX, XENON and LHC have eliminated many of the predicted masses for candidates for Dark Matter.  Does anyone know what the current lowest possible mass is that hasn't been eliminated through experiments?  What does that work out to in terms of cross section?

Comment: Do you mean that the LHC has set lower limits on the masses of supersymmetric particles that might form dark matter, and you're asking about those limits? The LHC itself is not an especially useful probe of dark matter compared to the many direct detection experiments done or in progress like [XENON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XENON).

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about those limits.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion

Comment: @probably_someone - The referenced article contains no useful information.  Did I miss something where they talked about the constraints on mass or cross section?

Comment: It also depends on what model of dark matter candidate you're talking about, there exists a very nice plot for the bounds set for WIMP nucleon scattering.. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Summary-for-spin-independent-WIMP-nucleon-scattering-results-Existing-limits-from-the_fig5_264050584

Comment: @DonaldAirey The mass of axions has been constrained to be $10^{-3}-10^{-5}$ eV, according to reference 1 in that article and the sidebar. But again, if you're talking about the constraints of **any** dark matter candidates, then there's probably something even lighter that someone has proposed as a dark matter candidate.

Comment: @probably_someone Oh yes, I've seen possibilities going down to $10^{-22}$eV, for example [here](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2275381/plots).  (I believe masses lower than that are not viable since they would correspond to de Broglie wavelengths larger than galactic scales.)  These are not pure thermal relics, which makes the mass and cross section independent.  Similarly, LUX et at. have not fully "eliminated" any range of dark matter masses; they've simply constrained possible DM--nucleon cross sections as a function of DM mass.

Answer (score 0):

No, these experiments have not ruled out any dark matter mass range. For a given dark matter mass, they have ruled out vast swathes of dark matter couplings. Those couplings and masses are very well motivated, but for any given mass, there could still be weaker or other couplings, that are still perfectly allowed.

Dark matter masses lighter than some $10^{-20}$eV have been ruled out by dwarf galaxies, and above asteroid mass (or if you are picky, above 10-solar-masses) have been ruled out e.g. by searches for gravitational microlenses and the stability of binaries. All masses in between are still perfectly allowed though.